# Arquillian, CDI 2.0 and JUnit 5/Jupiter

Tags: java, junit, jboss-arquillian

Do you have full support for JUnit 5/Jupiter?
It is possible to use ExtendWith annotation easily?

Such as these samples:

- https://dzone.com/articles/writing-tests-with-junit-5-and-cdi-20
- https://rmannibucau.metawerx.net/post/cdi-se-api-junit5-extension
- https://github.com/weld/weld-junit

```
@Cdi(disableDiscovery = true, classes = MyService.class)
class CdiTest {
    @Inject
    private MyService service;

    @Test
    void test() {
        assertEquals("ok", service.ok());
    }
}
```

Comment: I've created an issue and I would like to help with that:
https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-core/issues/233